# how to access class from inherited class

Tags: vb.net, class

I have two classes:

```
class class2
inherits class1

public sub modify()

'modify property of class1

end sub

end class
```

How can I modify class1 in a sub in class2?

Comment: what I am missing is the right keyword to point to class 1 from within class2

Comment: Yes but if you declare your property as `Protected` or `Public`, you don't even have to use a special keyword, since `Class2` inherits it, you'll see that it's like if the property was actually declared in `Class2`.

Comment: It might help if you include the definition of Class 1 to know what you want to do in the Modify method of class 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just call it.  Example:

```
Public Class class1
  Private _Value As String = String.Empty

  Property Value() As String
    Get
      Return _Value
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      _Value = value
    End Set
  End Property

End Class

Public Class class2
  Inherits class1

  Public Sub modify()
    Value = "modified"
  End Sub

End Class
```

And to show it works:

```
Dim c2 As New class2
c2.modify()
MessageBox.Show(c2.Value)
```

Comment: Cool, it is working now. No clue what I was doing that gave me these problem. Danks!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about properties, note that only `protected` and `public` properties are visible to inherited classes.
You need the `MyBase` keyword when you are overriding an existing function in the parent class. Other `protected` or `public` properties or functions can be accessed regulary without any special keyword.

Comment: As I said, you don't need to use MyBase for Public and Protected properties, just try access them as if they are declared in class2

Comment: that don't work either. Of course I have tried that before. The Error is: Error 1 on an instance member of a class can not be made without an explicit instance of a class of a / m shared method / member from.

Comment: @Delcon: could you add the method/property that you are trying to access from the inherited class to the question? It will be easier to see where is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One tip I wanted to add to the above comments regarding accessing base class info is where you have a base class without a default contructor or want to use a specific constructor This is a good opportunity to use Mybase. You have to call the constructor before any additional actions take place in this scenario.

```
Public Class MyClass
  Inherits baseClass
  Public Sub New()
   mybase.new("Oranges")
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class baseClass
Private _someVariable as String
Public Sub New(byval passedString as string)
   _someVariable = passedString
End Sub
End Class
```